# Manually populate an ImageField

Tags: ajax, django, file-upload

I have a `models.ImageField` which I sometimes populate with the corresponding [`forms.ImageField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#imagefield). Sometimes, instead of using a form, I want to update the image field with an ajax POST. I am passing both the image filename, and the image content (base64 encoded), so that in my api view I have everything I need. But I do not really know how to do this manually, since I have always relied in form processing, which automatically populates the `models.ImageField`.

How can I manually populate the `models.ImageField` having the filename and the file contents?

### EDIT

I have reached the following status:

```
instance.image.save(file_name, File(StringIO(data)))
instance.save()
```

And this is updating the file reference, using the right value configured in `upload_to` in the `ImageField`.

But **it is not saving the image**. I would have imagined that the first `.save` call would:

1. Generate a file name in the configured storage
2. Save the file contents to the selected file, including handling of any kind of storage configured for this `ImageField` (local FS, Amazon S3, or whatever)
3. Update the reference to the file in the `ImageField`

And the second `.save` would actually save the updated instance to the database.

What am I doing wrong? How can I make sure that the new image content is actually written to disk, in the automatically generated file name?

### EDIT2

I have a very unsatisfactory workaround, which is working but is very limited. This illustrates the problems that using the `ImageField` directly would solve:

```
# TODO: workaround because I do not yet know how to correctly populate the ImageField
# This is very limited because:
# - only uses local filesystem (no AWS S3, ...)
# - does not provide the advance splitting provided by upload_to
local_file = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, file_name)
with open(local_file, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)
instance.image = file_name
instance.save()
```

### EDIT3

So, after some more playing around I have discovered that my first implementation is doing the right thing, but silently failing if the passed data has the wrong format (I was mistakingly passing the base64 instead of the decoded data). I'll post this as a solution

Comment: I'm thinking you can save the image to a path, then you create your model like: `instance = Model()` `instance.imagefield = <image_path>` then `instance.save()`. Would that work?

Comment: @ShangWang: I want to avoid writing this code manually. ImageField already does this, and much more (support for different storages, split of files based on `upload_to`, etc). I want to reuse that functionality, cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

Just save the file and the instance:

```
instance.image.save(file_name, File(StringIO(data)))
instance.save()
```

No idea where the docs for this usecase are.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `InMemoryUploadedFile` directly to save data:

```
file = cStringIO.StringIO(base64.b64decode(request.POST['file']))
image = InMemoryUploadedFile(file,
   field_name='file',
   name=request.POST['name'],
   content_type="image/jpeg",
   size=sys.getsizeof(file),
   charset=None)
instance.image = image
instance.save()
```